# Setting a Hardware ID on an Android Tablet

Tags: hardware, antivirus

I wonder if I could get some guidance.

We purchased 6 android tablets for our kids over Christmas and shortly after we also purchased McAfee Live Safe so that we cold protect all these devices.  Now, McAfee's installation depends on a unique Hardware ID and it appears that from the manufacturer, the hardware ID on all devices are the same and have been rooted (Android 4.2).

Now, McAfee have no solution apart from refunding us our subscription as they are not able to resolve which means their application is not doing what it says on the tin.  this is all good but I have only found McAfee to provide an antivirus solution that will protect multiply devices.

I want to know if there is an easy way to set a Unique Hardware ID (like using the serial number of the device or the MAC address) so that I can install McAfee with no issues.

Anyone's help and guidance would be very much appreciated and I apologise in advance if this is the wrong place to ask but I have found many solutions from here in the past and thought I'd give it a go.

Comment: Did the folks at McAfee say anything about this "hardware ID"? It's not a lot to go on.

Answer (score 4):

Given that McAfee himself (who has had nothing to do with the software for years after selling it to Intel) describes the product as "[the worst software on the planet](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-25631183)", I'd take the refund and be grateful at dodging that bullet.

I won't recommend a particular one, but you could buy six copies of a competing Android security product for what a year's subscription to McAfee Live Safe costs.

Comment: Other antivirus programs likely won't ask for device unique information from you either.  It almost sounds like it was trying to look for an IMEI number or something of that nature, which wouldn't exist on a wifi based tablet.